# Is it good practice to define the use of the same namespace in the namespace declaration?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I was wondering, considering this code:

```
namespace A\B;
use A\B as AB;
use \Z\V as ZV; // another used namespace

class Merry {
   public static function Christmas{} 
}
```

My pro doing this is that, since in the whole application I refer to `Merry::Christmas()` as `AB\Merry::Christmas()`, I don't have to remember where I am when I'm coding and I just use `AB\Merry::Christmas()` everywhere. No confusion, no stupid PHP errors. Also it seems a little bit cleaner to me.

Is it good practice to define the `use` of a namespace inside the namespace declaration?

Comment: No one can prevent you from not thinking, however you need to type a lot of character combinations as namespaces when you don't want to remember any namespace. But then classes will clash.

Comment: @downvoter: Not a real question? Seriously?

Comment: @hakre, I don't think i got it. Classes will clash? How?

Comment: @hakre Also in my case there would be maximum 4-5 namespaces in the whole application. Not that hard to define...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see it as something to get excited about. As much as it lets you type `AB\Merry::Christmas();` everywhere, nothing ever stops you from just using: `\A\B\Merry::Christmas();`, which is only two more characters and doesn't need the `use` statement(s). That said, the extra `use` statement isn't harmful, so whatever floats your boat and works best with the particular application's namespace layout, do that.

Comment: The A and B in my example are just sample names. A could also be `Avyuwfiuuf` and `Boiuwegfig` in that way `AB` could mean `Avyuwfiuuf\Boiuwegfig`.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: Oh okay. That wasn't clear from the question. That makes some sense then. If you use the other name consistently it's shorter and clearer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the misunderstanding.